# Red squiggly when using Angular 2 in HTML file in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: html, visual-studio-2015, angular, resharper

When I use Angular 2 code in HTML files, I get red squiggly lines like so:

[image: squiggly]

If I hover my mouse over the red squiggly, no error or anything comes up.

Not sure if it's relevant, but I am using ReSharper Ultimate 10.0.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is a limitation in ReSharper. It's HTML parser doesn't handle the full range of characters the HTML5 spec allows, and that Angular2 takes advantage of. So, it's ReSharper reporting syntax errors (and not parsing the rest of the attributes correctly, either).

I've raised an issue you can track, comment and vote on: [RSRP-458056](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-458056)

Comment: Yeah, it's got to be Reshaper. When I disable it, the red squiggly goes away. Temporary fix for this: Resharper > Options > Code Inspection > Settings > File masks > add "*.html"

Comment: And you're right, I just double-checked in Resharper Ultimate 2016.1 EAP 10. This issue is still not fixed there.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Resharper fixed this issue in the latest update 2016.1.2